# Different pages related to website ip address

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, webserver, static-ip-address

My website is assigned a particular ip address.
Now, is there any way to configure web server like apache so that when I enter the website url in a browser, it shows a different page than when I enter the ip address related to the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. What you're looking for is apache [Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html).

You'll also need to configure your domain to point to your ip.